# Graph API calendarid is not unique and changing

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have noticed that the calendar `id` is not a unique value and it changes for reasons unknown.

I have stored some calendar `id` values in a database. At a later point when tried to insert events using those values, the `id` stored in database no longer matches the Calendar `id` in Microsoft Graph. Upon investigation the calendar `id` has been changed in the last few characters.

Can someone explain this anomaly please? any workarounds
Regards

Answer (score 2):

For an `event`, the `id` property is a composite value based on a number of other properties. If something changes (such as the path to the `item`), the `id` value will change. So while it is unique to a mailbox, it is not suitable for a permanent reference to the event.

With an `event`, you should use the `iCalUid` property. This is a unique value that is permanently persisted across all calendars. So even if the `event` is a meeting with multiple attendees, each attendee will persist the same `iCalUid` even if an attendee isn't part of your organization, or even on Exchange).

For the Calendar itself, I wouldn't expect the `id` to change unexpectedly (i.e. the user didn't delete and recreate or edit the calendar itself in some way).

Comment: Thanks for confirming and suggesting iCalUid. I did a quick look . how to get iCalUid values of a user's calendar ?

Comment: There isn't a `iCalUid` for a calendar, it is a property of the `event` on a calendar. I misread your question.The Calendar id shouldn't change unless they changed the calendar object itself in some specific ways. Are you seeing this happen often? It should be pretty rare. In those cases you need to request that the user re-select the calendar, no different than if they deleted a calendar.

Comment: So far I noticed that it changes when a user uses outlook desktop client after using o365 web . don't know if it is a one off change or if it can change randomly.

Comment: It would surprise me if switching clients would have any effect but I will ask around. Is it possible they renamed the calendar? Is it common for user's to not use their default calendar in your organization?

Comment: No the calendars were not renamed. We use default calendar as the primary calendar. will report any other patterns when calendar id changes. The calendar in question is a new calendar created by graph api.

Comment: Did this only happen to the calendar created via Graph or has this happened across multiple accounts over time?

Comment: This is happening across multiple user accounts but on the same calendar created by graph api. Didn't check if it is happening on other calendars .